# How to only check staged files with grunt-flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gruntjs, flowtype

I'm trying to figure out how to run the grunt-flow task to check only staged files.

At the moment, my grunt config file looks like this:

```
flow: {
        watch: {
            src: 'src/**/*.js',
            options: {
                server: true,
            },
        },
    },
```

With this configuration, the flow checker looks up the .flowconfig and check every file listed there regardless whether staged or not.